# Bing Maps Polygon InfoBox

Tags: maps, bing-maps, bing, infobox

I have setup a map with polygons around the countries on the map, and want to add an infobox so that on hover some information will be displayed for each country.

I can get infoboxes displaying easy enough without the polygons, but when assigning them to the PolygonOptions class, nothing happens. The docs say that so long as I have the Bing Themes module loaded (Which I do), the infoboxes will show up on hover and click.

There seems to be zero documentation/examples of this, so hoping you clever folks can help out.

Here is some of the relevant code;

```
    var center = this.map.getCenter();

    // Create an info box 
    var infoboxOptions = {
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        title: 'Testing', // sourceItems.data.dataset[0].data[index].key,
        description: "Visits: 20", // + sourceItems.data.dataset[0].data[index].visits,
        showPointer: true,
        titleClickHandler: this.polygonInfo,
        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(-100, 0),
        typeName: Microsoft.Maps.InfoboxType.mini,
        zIndex: 1000
    };
    var polyinfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(center, infoboxOptions);

    var polygonOptions = {
        fillColor: Microsoft.Maps.Color.fromHex(fillColour),
        strokeColor: Microsoft.Maps.Color.fromHex(fillColour),
        strokeThickness: 1,
        infobox: polyinfobox
    };

    var result = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(vertices, polygonOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a working code sample in the interactive SDK for the Bing Maps V7 control here: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#BingThemeModule6

Note that creating an infobox for each shape is very inefficient and will hurt performance if you have a lot of shapes. A better method is to have one infobox and dynamically populate it's data. I wrote a blog post on this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/multiple-pushpins-and-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/ If you want to use this approach here is a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, dataLayer, infobox;

        function GetMap()
        {  
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {
                credentials: "YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY"
            });

            dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
            map.entities.push(dataLayer);

            var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
            map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { visible: false });
            infoboxLayer.push(infobox);

            AddData();
        }

        function AddData(){
            var polygon = new Microsoft.Maps.Polygon([
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, -110), 
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(65, -90), 
                new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, -70)]);     

            polygon.Metadata = {
                title: 'Hello',
                description: 'World'
            };

            dataLayer.push(polygon);

            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon, 'click', displayInfobox);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(polygon, 'mouseover', displayInfobox);
        }

        function displayInfobox(e){
            if(e.target){
                var point = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(e.getX(), e.getY());       
                var loc = map.tryPixelToLocation(point);

                infobox.setLocation(loc);

                var opt = e.target.Metadata;

                if(opt){
                    if(e.target.getIcon){ //is pushpin
                        opt.offset = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,20);
                    }else{
                        opt.offset = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,0);
                    }

                    opt.visible = true;
                    infobox.setOptions(opt);
                }
            }
        }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetMap();">
      <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:600px; height:600px;"></div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah legend, thank you. I had hacked together something similar by myself, but this is much cleaner.